# Limiting number of concurrent users accessing a particular page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, concurrency, limit

I want to see how many users are on a particular page and limit future attempts by other users.  I have a radio station and using a simple swfobject to play music from my system to everyone.

It works just fine, but I want to limit the number of concurrent users on the radio page ONLY.  The users can be on any page without listening to radio, but limit the concurrent users on this particular page.

How do I do that?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Its not so easy as its sounds because you need to monitor if the user is still on that page, and what if a user opens many windows for the same page ?... and what if the user listening radio not from your page but from the link that provide the music ?

Comment: How you provide the music ? I think the link that provide the music must be limited and not the page.

Comment: Aristos, I don't see a reason why the user would open two windows.  I mean, they open 2 windows and pause in one and play in another.  Yeah, there will be users like that, but I don't expect many.  I have MP3s in my hard drive and a flash mp3 player which plays from the hard drive.

Comment: because anyone that wish to hack your site, its open many windows and stop the real users. You need to check the mp3 downloads ! and not the pages.

Comment: Whether you are able to arrive on any solid solution for this issue? If so can you please share the same here. Thanks,
Rajeev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aristos pointed out, this is easier said than done:

You can easily track how many have opened the page, but if they leave via an html link you will not be able to know they left.

There are ways to get around this which may not be very accurate or elegant.

You could use AJAX to keep tabs on who is still on the page by polling the web service. If the system doesn't get back a response for the particular id in a certain amount of time you can infer that the user has left.

Comment: Nick, I can improve from your idea.  I'll issue a 'token' before playing the music and keep polling that for existence of that 'token' and allow/disallow new users based on that.  Also, I have a robust 'on exit' javascript/ajax routine which I can use to capture the exit event.

Answer (score 1):

If you can isolate your actual player to its on site on IIS, like radio.yoursite.com you can throttle the connections easily using [IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/83d66f47-8184-4d25-afcf-c229fffdc981.mspx?mfr=true), the link is to IIS 6, but 7 should have a similar option. I guess the point I'm trying to make is that it would be a challenging task to do at the page level, but if you do it at the site level, it might be easier, an option if you can move your radio to its own IIS site.